# Android and Facebook SDK - Is RequestAsyncTask still working after my application exits?

Tags: android, facebook

Request may take some time to complete (for example when uploading a video).

Is it still running after the user exits my application?

Answer (score 1):

It's running on a separate thread, so it should continue to run unless the user kills the application process. One way to get around that is to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to run the thread. That way if the user kills the application process, the thread isn't tied to it. You can show the progress in the notifications. This is a pretty standard convention for uploading/downloading files.